# Compare all the values in the list by mapping

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

I have a conditional statement to compare if the value is error or not. I have a list of values and I need a way to write the conditional statement to check all the values in the list. This is the code that stores a list of values:

[image: screenshot of code with the debugger showing the contents of this.props.notificationList]

I am writing the below conditional code but I could only get the first element in the array. I need a possible way to check the entire list and compare it here.

```
this.props.notificationList[0].Level === "error"
```

Comment: this.props.notificationList.every(item => item.Level === "error")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a list of values and i need a way to write the conditional statement to check all the values in the listthis code stores a list of values

- If any single error is a failure

Use Array.prototype.some : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

e.g. `this.props.notificationList[0].Level === "error"` becomes:

```
this.props.notificationList.some(n => n.Level==="error");
```

- If all errors are considered a failure

Use `every` instead of `some`.

Comment: AWESOME. IT WORKED

Answer (score 0):

To return a new ordered array where each item in the new array is whether or not the corresponding item has an error:

```
const errorsList = this.props.notificationList.map(item => item.Level === "error");
```

To return a single boolean indicating if any item has an error:

```
const anyError = this.props.notificationList.some(item => item.Level === "error");
```